# Get input Value from Repeater with Request.Item

Tags: javascript, vb.net

this question may have been asked around before but somehow i can't find the awsner...

On my Default.aspx i have a repeater, that i put data on it with Databinder.Eval.

But what i want to do next is after i click the Image i want a Response of the values in inputs (hidden) that are next the images.

Here is my code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <table class="table-hover" style="margin: 20px auto;">
                <asp:Repeater ID="rpRow" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img style="margin: 5px;" id="ImageBar" src="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageBar")%>" onclick="<%= _imgPostBackCall %>;"/>
                                <input id="PromoID_<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PromoID")%>" type="hidden" name="PromoID" value="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PromoID")%>" />
                                <input id="PromoCode_<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PromoCode")%>" type="hidden" name="PromoCode" value="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PromoCode")%>" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Code behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        _imgPostBackCall = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Me, "")

        If Not Me.IsPostBack Then

            'DataTable
            Dim dt_Data As DataTable = PromoDL.GetPromo()

            'Table list
            rpRow.DataSource = dt_Data
            rpRow.DataBind()

            dt_Data.Dispose()
        Else
            'Event Click


            Dim PromoID As String = Request.Item("PromoID")
            Dim PromoCode As String = Request.Item("PromoCode")
            Response.Write("PromoID: " & PromoID & " PromoCode: " & PromoCode)
        End If
    End Sub
```

What i get on Response is something like this

> PromoID: 3,1 PromoCode: BFC40,BFCN20

(Which are the 2 rows i have on my DB), but what i want is it to appear like this

> PromoID: 3 PromoCode: BFC40

(which corresponds to what image i clicked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I was making things way more complicated.
All i needed to do was put an `<a>` inside the repeater, like this:

```
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <table class="table-hover" style="margin: 20px auto;">
                <asp:Repeater ID="rpRow" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <a href="Promo.aspx?Code=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PromoCode")%>">
                                    <img style="margin: 5px;" id="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PromoCode")%>" src="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImageBar")%>" />
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```